# vscoce-clangd can not find the boost headers

Tags: c++

The error message is:

> 'boost/program_options.hpp' file not foundclang(pp_file_not_found)

The `compile_flags.txt` has this config:

```
-Wall
-std=c++17
-I /usr/local/include 
-L /usr/local/lib
```

How to config clangd to find boost lib?

Comment: Add `-I /path/to/include/directory` to your compiler flags